# Matching with less boilerplate

Tags: rust

I have nested structures of `enums`, ie. `enum X` has a variant which contains `enum Y` etc. Is there any way to access fields eg `x.y.z` with a runtime error if `x.y.z` doesn't exist (eg, `x` is of wrong variant). Furthermore is this a reasonably moral thing to do, or is there a better alternative, without `match` statements everywhere? Efficiency is not so important, though it would be good to make it as cheap as possible.

Comment: It would be easier to understand exactly what you wish if you could present some sample code of what the enums look like and which syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to access nested enums with dots syntax, but you can use `if let`:

```
pub enum X {
    A(Y),
    B(Z)
}

pub enum Y {
    C,
    D(u32)
}

pub enum Z {
    E
}

fn main() {
    let x = X::A(Y::D(12));

    if let X::A(Y::D(n)) = x {
        println!("Got it: {}", n);
    } else {
        println!("Nope");
    }
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/nbWRsJ))

`if let` makes the code arguably more concise than `match`. Naturally, this is as efficient as `match`.

Answer (score 4):

Given these definitions:

```
enum X {
    Variant(Y),
    …
}

enum Y {
    Variant(Z),
    …
}

struct Z;
```

You can use `if let` with deep patterns as one way:

```
if let X::Variant(Y::Variant(ref z) = x {
    // Use z
} else {       // And these two lines are,
    panic!();  // of course, optional.
}
```

Or you could define methods (panicking is not a good idea, though; having such methods return `Option` is much more common, as is shown in rustc_serialize’s `Json` enum, for example), but it will still leave you with comparatively ugly code, probably):

```
impl X {
    fn y(&self) -> &Y {
        match *self {
            Variant(ref y) => y,
            _ => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

// Ditto for Y.z()

let z = x.y().z();
```